# segmentation fault 11 in c binary search tree

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to print the nodes in my binary tree. It looks to be an issue with the third node. I have searched google and stack overflow for hours but I can not understand what the problem is. I am trying to teach myself data structures in C and am very much a novice so I may be doing something in a frowned upon way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *left;
  struct node *right;
} Node;

typedef struct
{
  Node *root;
} BinarySearchTree;

void printInOrder(Node *);
void addNode(Node *, Node *);

int main (void)
{
  BinarySearchTree tree;
  BinarySearchTree *tree_ptr = &tree; 
  Node n1, n2, n3;

  n1.data = 1;
  n2.data = 2;
  n3.data = 3;

  Node *n1_ptr = &n1;
  Node *n2_ptr = &n2;
  Node *n3_ptr = &n3;

  tree_ptr->root = n1_ptr;

  addNode(tree_ptr->root, n2_ptr);
  addNode(tree_ptr->root, n3_ptr);
  printInOrder(tree_ptr->root);
}

void printInOrder(Node *root)
{
  if (root == NULL)
  {
    return;
  } else
  {
    printInOrder(root->left);
    printf("%i\n", root->data);
    printInOrder(root->right);
  }
}

void addNode(Node *root, Node *node)
{
  if (node->data < root->data)
  {
    if (root->left == NULL)
    {
      root->left = node;
    } else
    {
      addNode(root->left, node);
    }
  } 

  else if (node->data > root->data)
  {
    if (root->right == NULL)
    {
      root->right = node;
    } else
    {
      addNode(root->right, node);
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```
1
2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

There doesn't seem to be an issue with any but the third node. If I comment out the line that adds the second node I get the same error (with only 1 being printed, obviously).

Comment: Where do you initialize the *full* `Node` structure? I don't see you set their `left` or `right` pointers anywhere.

Comment: And what happens if, in the `add_node` function, `node->data == root->data`?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong with the first struct? Or are you referring to when I set them in the addNode function? I apologize I am very new to C and don't fully understand the question.

Comment: Nothing happens for that case yet. I will write the functionality for that after I figure out how to correctly add a node to the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initialization is incomplete

```
  n1.data = 1;
  n2.data = 2;
  n3.data = 3;
```

should also set the pointers

```
  n1.data = 1;
  n1.left = NULL;
  n1.right = NULL;

  n2.data = 2;
  n2.left = NULL;
  n2.right = NULL;

  n3.data = 3;
  n3.left = NULL;
  n3.right = NULL;
```

Comment: Is there a reason why I don't have to do this for n1 and n2? the segmentation fault only happens with the third node (n3).

Comment: @pariscraigm - You shall do it for all. Using an uninitialized variable (pointer variable) can give a crash but does **not** always give a crash. The only safe thing is to make sure to initialize before use - always.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is occurring because you are not initializing all the member of structure `Node` type variable.

I would suggest, you should write a function to initialize the `Node` type variable, like this:

```
void init_node(Node * nodeptr, int data)
{
        nodeptr->data = data;
        nodeptr->left = NULL;
        nodeptr->right = NULL;
}
```

and in your `main()` (or from where ever you want to initialize) you can simply do:

```
  init_node(&n1, 1);
  init_node(&n2, 2);
  init_node(&n3, 3);
```

With this, you will never miss assigning NULL to `left` and `right` pointer during initialization of `Node` type variable and chances of the error occurring because of it will be reduced to a greater extent.